# Exclude an OU from All Recipients distribution group in Exchange 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2003

I'm running an Exchange 2003 SP2 mail server on an Active Directory domain. Domain functional level is Windows 2008.
The All Recipients distribution group encompasses all of my domain and i want to exclude one OU from it so that when a user sends an email to All Recipients, users under that OU don't receive that email.

Any advice on how to perform that?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used 2003, but I'm not sure this is possible. Query-based Distribution Groups only allow you to pick one OU and you get every user that's in it.

The way we approached this was to create several QBDGs for all of the other OUs and then to combine them as members of the main group. It wasn't pretty, but we didn't have many OUs, so it worked out ok for us.

Comment: I was going to post the same solution, as it's what I'd done in the past as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it is to set a custom attribute on the users (ExcludeFromAllRecipients for eg) then set a custom filter on the QBDG for All Recipients to check Custom Attribute isNot ExcludeFromAllRecpients

You can then easily select all the users in a given OU and set the custom attribute

Comment: Thanks, my problem is I'm an Exchange newbie. I managed to set the custom attribute for the users in the OU i want to exclude. But how can i create the custom filter in the All Recipients QBDG?